# Maximum recursion depth exceeded when finding the depth of binary-search-tree

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree

This is my code:

```
# increase the limit of recursion
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)
import numpy as np

# make binary search tree from list
def bst_build(seq):
    binary_search_tree = [seq[0], None, None]
    seq.pop(0)

    def add_child(main, sub):
        if len(sub) != 0:
            if main[0] > sub[0]:
                if main[1] == None:
                    main.pop(1)
                    main.insert(1, [sub[0], None, None])
                    sub.pop(0)
                    add_child(binary_search_tree, sub)
                else:
                    add_child(main[1], sub)
            
            elif main[0] < sub[0]:
                if main[2] == None:
                    main.pop(2)
                    main.insert(2, [sub[0], None, None])
                    sub.pop(0)
                    add_child(binary_search_tree, sub)        
                else:
                    add_child(main[2], sub)
            else:
                sub.pop(0)         
        else:
            pass

    add_child(binary_search_tree, seq)

    return binary_search_tree

# check the correctness
def bst_check(b):
    if b is None: return True
    if b[1] is not None:
        if b[1][0] >= b[0]: return False
        if bst_check(b[1]) == False: return False
    if b[2] is not None:
        if b[2][0] <= b[0]: return False
        if bst_check(b[2]) == False: return False
    return True

# find depth of binary search tree
def bst_depth(b):
    maximum_depth = 0
    current_depth = 0

    def find_depth(tree):
        nonlocal maximum_depth
        nonlocal current_depth

        if len(tree) != 1:
            if tree[1] != None and len(tree[1]) != 1:
                current_depth += 1
                find_depth(tree[1])
            else:
                tree.pop(1)
                if maximum_depth <= current_depth:
                    maximum_depth = current_depth
                current_depth = 0
                find_depth(b)
        else:
            pass  
    find_depth(b)      

    return maximum_depth

unsorted = list(np.random.randint(0,100,10))
sorted = unsorted.copy()
sorted.sort()

t1 = bst_build(unsorted)
t2 = bst_build(sorted)

print(t1)
print(t2)

print(bst_check(t1), bst_check(t2))
print( bst_depth(t1), bst_depth(t2) )
```

First, I make a binary search tree from a list, and check whether it is a binary search tree.

The first element of given list is the root node, and following elements become the child nodes. `None` is appended to leaf nodes.

For example, the result of calling `bst_build([4, 2, 1, 3, 6, 5, 7])` is:

```
[4, 
  [2, 
    [1, None, None], 
    [3, None, None]
  ], 
  [6, 
    [5, None, None],
    [7, None, None]]
  ]
]
```

The result is a binary search tree because the left child node is smaller than the parent node and the right child node is larger than the parent node. Therefore the result of calling `bst_child` is `True`.

Then I added the code that finds the depth of the binary search tree.
I made two different binary search trees by sorting the first list.

In this case, the first list is `[4,2,1,3,6,5,7]` and the second list is  `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, which is sorted.

The depth of binary search tree built from the first list is 2, while the one built from the sorted list is 6.

```
unsorted = [4,2,1,3,6,5,7]
sorted = unsorted.copy()
sorted.sort()

t1 = bst_build(unsorted)
t2 = bst_build(sorted)

print(t1)
print(t2)
print(bst_check(t1), bst_check(t2))
print( bst_depth(t1), bst_depth(t2) )
```

Output is (after pretty printing the nested lists):

```
[4, 
  [2, 
    [1, None, None], 
    [3, None, None]
  ], 
  [6, 
    [5, None, None],
    [7, None, None]]
  ]
]

[1, None, 
  [2, None, 
    [3, None,
      [4, None,
        [5, None,
          [6, None,
            [7, None, None]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]

True True
2 6
```

I thought that I made the binary search tree and the code finding depth well.
But when I tried with a long list, my vscode could not print proper result.

When I tried with the list whose length is 20, it worked.

```
unsorted = list(np.random.randint(0,1000,20))
sorted = unsorted.copy()
sorted.sort()

t1 = bst_build(unsorted)
t2 = bst_build(sorted)

print(bst_check(t1), bst_check(t2))
print( bst_depth(t1), bst_depth(t2) )
```

Output:

```
True True
5 19
```

However, When the length of list is about 30, it does not work.
The length of the sorted list is 30, but the result is not 29 but some other number, such as 3, or a recursion error occurs:

> maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

So I increased the recursion limit by adding the `sys.setrecursionlimit`.

Then my code works until the length of list is about 40~50.

But when the length of list is over 50, this method still gets into the same issue. I also tried with `sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000)` or over millions, but it doesn't help.

Even sometimes nothing is printed.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There is a reason why python sets a relatively low recursion limit. If you have to start your program with `sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)`, that's a good sign that something is wrong with your code. Note that the height of a balanced binary tree is logarithmic in its number of elements. Logarithms are ***small***. For instance, if the binary tree contains 10000000 (10 million) elements, then its height should be only about 25. So you shouldn't need a recursion limit over 30 or so. Don't increase the recursion limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursion depth should not be that great on the condition that your binary tree is relatively balanced. Still, even when your binary tree is *degenerate*, like is what happens when you create it from a sorted sequence (`sorted`) then you should still only need O(n) stack space.

But your code for both `bst_build` and `find_depth` needs a lot more stack space. This is because they don't backtrack when reaching a leaf. Instead they both restart a traversal from the *root*, without getting out of the *current* recursion tree first:

- `bst_build` does this by calling `bst_build` again when it wants to insert the next input from `seq`. This should happen in a loop (outside of recursion), not when you are already deep in a recursion tree.
- `find_depth` does this by calling `find_depth` again when it reaches a leaf. This should happen by first backtracking one step and then recurring again into a sibling node. Instead it restarts the search from the root (which is a waste of time), and does so without getting out of recursion first.

This makes this code need a tremendous amount of stack space, which will be like O(n²) in the worst (degenerate) case.

Not related to your question, but it is a pity -- and completely unnecessary -- that `find_depth` destroys the tree as it is being traversed.

Another problem that is not related to your question: your `bst_check` is not correct. It will return True for the following tree:

```
            2
           /
          1
           \
            3
```

Yet, this tree is not a valid BST. The requirement for a valid BST is not only that a left child is less than its parent, but that *all nodes in the left subtree* are less than that parent.

Here is a fix for all these issues:

```
def bst_build(seq):
    if not seq:
        return None

    def add_child(main, value):
        if value == main[0]:
            return
        childindex = 1 if main[0] > value else 2
        if not main[childindex]:
            main[childindex] = [value, None, None]
        else:
            add_child(main[childindex], value)

    binary_search_tree = [seq[0], None, None]
    for value in seq[1:]:
        add_child(binary_search_tree, value)

    return binary_search_tree


def bst_depth(b):
    return 1 + max(bst_depth(b[1]) if b[1] else -1, bst_depth(b[2]) if b[2] else -1)


def bst_check(b, low=float("-inf"), high=float("inf")):
    return not b or (low <= b[0] <= high and bst_check(b[1], low, b[0]) 
                                         and bst_check(b[2], b[0], high))
```